# Android app:dex:Debug error - cannot seem to solve

Tags: java, android

please see the link attached for the exact error.

Can run any other android projects, the one I am trying to run simply refuses to work:

https://gyazo.com/bc05c903dddc7dd3b79f9979d6bc42aa

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tapthatstudios.fingersoffury"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: are you kidding? this is like.. "my car isnt starting.. why is my fridge not cooling?" how about providing some code so we can actually figure out what the error is about? all we know so far is that you even striped away the wrong parts in that screenshot.

Comment: My bad, new to the website. I'll upload the parts now

Comment: Do you have a support library in your libs folder? If you do, gradle will complain about duplicate classes since you are already including the support library in your project. You should also make sure you have downloaded the support libraries in the Android SDK.

Comment: The image you posted just says that there where some errors. You have to look in the previous lines to see the specific erros.